# Using Flash Player Offline

Tags: security, flash, flash-player, adobe-flash

I'm trying out a new Flash sound library, but I keep running into security issues when I try to run the test everything offline.

Specifically, i'm trying to work with [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). I have downloaded and unpacked the SDK onto my desktop but none of the demos work when I open them with any browser (they all work online though). When I open the troubleshoot index file, I get an error that points me to the [Flash Security Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) panel, and tells me to add a trusted path.

Other sources online say the same thing about offline files needing an exception listed in the Flash Global Security panel. I tried this a few different ways though and nothing happened:

[image: my flash global security panel]

No matter what path I add, or even if I select "Always Allow", I still get the same flash security error in the SM2 test. What am I doing wrong / how can I get flash to work when viewing files offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions.

First one is to set up an ad hoc local server like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). Deploying it takes few minutes and you don't have to install anything. When you don't need it anymore, you just delete the folder and you're done. Files served through XAMPP will have online privileges, but you won't have to actually be online.

The second solution is to use Flash Player Projector (you can get it [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)). It's meant to run Flash files locally, maybe it will ignore security settings - worth giving it a try.

Comment: FP Projector didn't work - its a standalone swf player, can't open full web pages. XAMPP got it working though.